# Android : java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json, loopj

I am getting `json` Exception while trying to parse a string to jsonArray. I am using `loopj` method for `json` Parsing. This is the error :

```
java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

And this is the json I am trying to parse :

```
[{\"displayName\":\"Thiruvananthapuram\",\"desc\":\"Partly cloudy\",\"cloudCover\":\"5\",\"dateTime\":\"Sunday October 02\",\"humidity\":\"85\",\"visibility\":\"10\",\"tempCelcius\":\"29\",\"iconClass\":\"PartlyCloudy-s\"}]
```

My code is

```
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
   client.get("url", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {

        try {
        String jsonStr = new String(responseBody, "UTF-8");
        Log.e("Tag ", "on Result " + jsonStr);
        JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                Log.e("Tag ", "jsonArr length " + jsonarray.length());
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
        }
    })
```

Comment: replace slashes with "" maybe help you

Comment: i tried jsonStr = jsonStr.replaceAll("[\]",""); but no user @dariush f

Comment: you replaced brackets ([]) , do this : jsonStr = jsonStr.replaceAll("\","");

Comment: after replaceing am getting error "Value [{ of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray"  @dariush f

Comment: @BinilSurendran Any luck?

Comment: yes, I just remove "\" and the result that am getting from API having invert-er comma at the startand end. So I just take substring, remove first character and last character. After that its work , Thanks @K Neeraj Lal @Sarbjyot

Answer (score 1):

First you have to get jsonObject using jsonString using line below

```
JSONObject jsnobject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
```

Then you can iterate through the jsonObject to get jsonArray object.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsnobject.getJSONArray("your json array key");
```

Comment: json array key means , there is no key for jsonArray, In the result i have only one array@ascii_walker

Comment: for jsonFile like this:
 { "orgList": [ { "orgInfo": { "id": 1, "orgName": "Organization X" }, {},{}...}
Key for jsonArray is : orgList

Comment: here the reult is JsonArray not JsonObject  [{\"displayName\":\"Thiruvananthapuram\",\"desc\":\"Partly cloudy\",\"cloudCover\":\"5\",\"dateTime\":\"Sunday October 02\",\"humidity\":\"85\",\"visibility\":\"10\",\"tempCelcius\":\"29\",\"iconClass\":\"PartlyCloudy-s\"}] @ascii_walker

Comment: You can replace "\" with "" to make it look like normal json then you can parse it by iterating through key value pair of json array

Comment: after replaceing am getting error "Value [{ of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray" @ascii_walker

Comment: Its seem you dont have key in you json string append a key in your json string:  "jsonArrayKey":[{a:b},{aa:bb},{},....]

Answer (score 0):

you have to replace the "\" to "" then convert into the JsonArray:-

example:-

```
 String jsonStr = new String(responseBody, "UTF-8");

jsonStr = jsonStr.replace("\","");

// now convert it into JsonArray
  JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
```

hope this help you...